# How to assert an element based on its Text - Selenium WebDriver with JAVA

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium webdriver, and I came up with a certain scenario.
There is a drop down list, and user selects one of the values (Text). The selected value (text) is now displayed on the drop down field.

I want to know how can I extract the text out of that element (div) and then assert it with the selected value (text).

The HTML of the element is:

```
<div class="kac-entry kac-select kac-display ng-binding" ng-click="toggleDropdown()" ng-hide="shouldShowPlaceholder()" ng-class="{btn: btnStyle, 'btn-primary': btnStyle}" style="">      ^NYA (NYSE COMPOSITE INDEX (NEW METHOD))   </div>
```

The xpath of the above element is:

```
//price-trigger[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/k-select/div/div[1]
```

The text in the HTML element is ^NYA (NYSE COMPOSITE INDEX (NEW METHOD)). I want to get this title and check if this is the option (value) that user actually selected or not.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("groupSelect")));
```

if you want to select by xpath

```
By.xpath("//price-trigger[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/k-select/div/div[1]")

Assert.assertEquals("Please select any option...", select);
```

Syntax:

```
String selectedOption = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Type the xpath of the drop-down element"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();

Assert.assertEquals("Please select any option...", selectedOption);
```

More in detailed on selecting value from dropdown

```
<html>
<body>
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>
</select>
<body>
</html>
```

Now to identify dropdown do

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));
```

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByValue("prog");
```